# Access an object in a loop

Tags: php, oop, object, foreach

I am currently struggling to loop through an object and get the data i need from it, I am trying to access the modules section of the object, by doing this,

```
foreach ($project->modules as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key => $value\n";
        }
```

however I get the following error,

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I have added the object as I think this might help someone help me with my problem.

```
(
    [id] => 10750777
    [name] => Scandanavian stairs CGI interiors project
    [published_on] => 1378374328
    [created_on] => 1378374073
    [modified_on] => 1378375326
    [url] => https://www.behance.net/gallery/Scandanavian-stairs-CGI-interiors-project/10750777
    [privacy] => public
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Computer Animation
            [1] => Digital Art
            [2] => Set Design
        )

    [covers] => stdClass Object
        (
            [404] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/10750777/404/f5324dd8a81af4113e252cf9931a91ce.jpeg
            [202] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/10750777/orig/f5324dd8a81af4113e252cf9931a91ce.jpeg
            [230] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/10750777/230/f5324dd8a81af4113e252cf9931a91ce.jpeg
            [115] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/projects/10750777/115/f5324dd8a81af4113e252cf9931a91ce.jpeg
        )

    [mature_content] => 0
    [mature_access] => allowed
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [views] => 407
            [appreciations] => 35
            [comments] => 4
        )

    [for_sale] => 0

    [modules] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274743
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274743/disp/8188649c438a044fa71cc81d79d5fbdb.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 602
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274743/orig/8188649c438a044fa71cc81d79d5fbdb.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274743/hd/8188649c438a044fa71cc81d79d5fbdb.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274743/fs/8188649c438a044fa71cc81d79d5fbdb.jpg
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274745
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274745/disp/064d0fa0f94b4bc4ff19a658cf8d944d.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274745/orig/064d0fa0f94b4bc4ff19a658cf8d944d.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274745/hd/064d0fa0f94b4bc4ff19a658cf8d944d.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274745/fs/064d0fa0f94b4bc4ff19a658cf8d944d.jpg
                        )

                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274747
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274747/disp/e161fec88a040777df812e7426dcc3e5.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274747/orig/e161fec88a040777df812e7426dcc3e5.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274747/hd/e161fec88a040777df812e7426dcc3e5.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274747/fs/e161fec88a040777df812e7426dcc3e5.jpg
                        )

                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274749
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274749/disp/dc7d64acb8b1d3c4248addc5d1d86b15.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 583
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274749/orig/dc7d64acb8b1d3c4248addc5d1d86b15.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274749/hd/dc7d64acb8b1d3c4248addc5d1d86b15.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274749/fs/dc7d64acb8b1d3c4248addc5d1d86b15.jpg
                        )

                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274751
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274751/disp/353f5fc7eb8dcba53a1363db3bb61248.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 323
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274751/orig/353f5fc7eb8dcba53a1363db3bb61248.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274751/hd/353f5fc7eb8dcba53a1363db3bb61248.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274751/fs/353f5fc7eb8dcba53a1363db3bb61248.jpg
                        )

                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274753
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274753/disp/19f4de08e95d14a1765c8441236e2b18.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274753/orig/19f4de08e95d14a1765c8441236e2b18.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274753/hd/19f4de08e95d14a1765c8441236e2b18.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274753/fs/19f4de08e95d14a1765c8441236e2b18.jpg
                        )

                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274755
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274755/disp/312c55cfe37832960944fba4090524fe.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 266
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274755/orig/312c55cfe37832960944fba4090524fe.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274755/hd/312c55cfe37832960944fba4090524fe.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274755/fs/312c55cfe37832960944fba4090524fe.jpg
                        )

                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274757
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274757/disp/1c35f30389308705f2bd7e20e5092e95.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274757/orig/1c35f30389308705f2bd7e20e5092e95.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274757/hd/1c35f30389308705f2bd7e20e5092e95.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274757/fs/1c35f30389308705f2bd7e20e5092e95.jpg
                        )

                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274759
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274759/disp/200de13606d4e8091a1ac9f54a06dbfc.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 323
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274759/orig/200de13606d4e8091a1ac9f54a06dbfc.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274759/hd/200de13606d4e8091a1ac9f54a06dbfc.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274759/fs/200de13606d4e8091a1ac9f54a06dbfc.jpg
                        )

                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274761
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274761/disp/8d516b209a73216dec78e0f9f29088c0.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274761/orig/8d516b209a73216dec78e0f9f29088c0.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274761/hd/8d516b209a73216dec78e0f9f29088c0.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274761/fs/8d516b209a73216dec78e0f9f29088c0.jpg
                        )

                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274763
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274763/disp/32d15fa3ad7426f45d616eb5565cd2a4.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274763/orig/32d15fa3ad7426f45d616eb5565cd2a4.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274763/hd/32d15fa3ad7426f45d616eb5565cd2a4.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274763/fs/32d15fa3ad7426f45d616eb5565cd2a4.jpg
                        )

                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274765
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274765/disp/2f8156030a6d553751a8ff8c501696f2.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 323
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274765/orig/2f8156030a6d553751a8ff8c501696f2.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274765/hd/2f8156030a6d553751a8ff8c501696f2.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274765/fs/2f8156030a6d553751a8ff8c501696f2.jpg
                        )

                )

            [12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274767
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274767/disp/79fa8373472ccdb35c20bf4ac3a803d3.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274767/orig/79fa8373472ccdb35c20bf4ac3a803d3.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274767/hd/79fa8373472ccdb35c20bf4ac3a803d3.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274767/fs/79fa8373472ccdb35c20bf4ac3a803d3.jpg
                        )

                )

            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274769
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274769/disp/6067d0e7500c3e44a6f9a8d902653a4d.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 322
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274769/orig/6067d0e7500c3e44a6f9a8d902653a4d.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274769/hd/6067d0e7500c3e44a6f9a8d902653a4d.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274769/fs/6067d0e7500c3e44a6f9a8d902653a4d.jpg
                        )

                )

            [14] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78274771
                    [type] => image
                    [src] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274771/disp/5aa7ce273e5f3dff20e36d2543b71b86.jpg
                    [width] => 600
                    [height] => 450
                    [sizes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [original] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274771/orig/5aa7ce273e5f3dff20e36d2543b71b86.jpg
                            [max_1240] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274771/hd/5aa7ce273e5f3dff20e36d2543b71b86.jpg
                            [max_1920] => https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/78274771/fs/5aa7ce273e5f3dff20e36d2543b71b86.jpg
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: The elements of the `modules` array are not strings, they're objects. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: $value is an object, not a string. Implement toString() in that object, or use var_export to print it.

Comment: What data do you need from each module? You can see the available properties in the `print_r()` output.

Comment: I need to get the sizes object from the modules object

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo an object.

Try using `echo "$key => "; print_r($value);`